# How do cards that generate restricted mana work with Kruphix and Omnath?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Kruphix, God of Horizons](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKruphix%2c%20God%20of%20Horizons%5d) makes it so mana, instead of emptying, turns colorless. On a similar note, [Omnath, Locus of Mana](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmnath%2c%20Locus%20of%20Mana%5d), makes it so green mana does not empty between phases. How do these effects work with restricted mana, like mana generated with [Food Chain](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFood%20Chain%5d) or [Shrine of the Forsaken Gods](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShrine%20of%20the%20Forsaken%20Gods%5d)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's still the same mana —it simply changes/loses/gains color— so the restrictions remain.

From Kruphix's Gather rulings:

> 4/26/2014 If unused mana in your mana pool has any restrictions or riders associated with it (for example, if it was produced by Cavern of Souls), those restrictions or riders will remain associated with that mana when it becomes colorless.

From Omnath's rulings:

> 3/1/2010  If a green mana you add to your mana pool has certain restrictions or riders associated with it (for example, if it was produced by Ancient Ziggurat), they’ll apply to that mana no matter when you spend it.

Comment: It might be worth noting how the interaction works between Kruphix and Omnath, i.e. Omnath states that Green mana doesn't empty, therefore Kruphix's ability doesn't affect green mana, as the trigger of his ability is upon unused mana emptying.  Therefore with both in play, green mana will not empty, and will not be converted into colourless mana by Kruphix.

Comment: @DoctorJones Yes, but that isn't relevant to their interaction with restricted mana.  The interaction is similar (and has the same root causes), but is not directly related.

Comment: @DoctorJones Is Omnath a straight up "Emptying no longer happens", or is it classified as a replacement effect (emptying is replaced by not emptying)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that it has been errata'd, which makes it even more clear, the text now reads, "**You don't lose unspent green mana** as steps and phases end", and "**If you would lose unspent mana**, that mana becomes colorless instead".  The trigger is "if you lose", and the effect of Omnath is "you don't lose", so that seems pretty clear cut, the trigger will not happen for green mana as long as Omnath is in play.